# Appending in Windows File - Null Characters Appearing

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-8, informatica, codepages

I'm creating Windows file through Informatica using codepage UTF 8 ( I tried other code pages as well). First I'm creating/writing file with header record and then appending detail records in same file. The issue is there are Null Characters appearing in between header and first detail record. Could anyone advise why Null Characters are appearing and how can they be removed?  Thanks

Comment: what's the source? how u are populating it?

Comment: Source is a file and it is not getting any null character and the issue is when I'm writing header and detail in separate file then we are not getting any null character but when I'm writing detail record in same file of header then we are getting these null characters after header record

Comment: Is the header file a fixed length or delimeted file? Are you creating the two files in same mapping (and using target load plan to control which gets created first) or separate mappings?

Comment: Not sure why you've been downvoted given this is a valid issue. Please share the details I've asked for

Comment: Check your character encoding again. When I had a similar problem, it was because the source really was UTF-16 encoded, not UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of things you have to look at,

1. Check the source , whether you are getting that null character from the source.
2. Cross check the transformation used once.

Even after that if you are getting the NULL character , then go ahead and delete the those NULL character from the file using BATCH script that will be called in the post success command.

Comment: Source is a file and it is not getting any null character and the issue is when I'm writing header and detail in separate file then we are not getting any null character but when I'm writing detail record in same file of header then we are getting these null characters after header record

Comment: I am not getting your whole scenario, still I suggest while you loading details data , In session property , select "No header " option